# firebase scheduled function parameter type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using a scheduled firebase function and want to specify a type for "context" to write it in .ts. Is there an URL for me to find out the type documentation? and specifically, what is the type for this "context" parameter?

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes").onRun((context:any)
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the `context` variable is an [`EventContext` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext).

This is found in the [Cloud Functions SDK Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions) as part of the [`ScheduleBuilder` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_pubsub_.schedulebuilder#onrun).

For a PubSub Cloud Function, `context` will look like:

```js
{
  auth: undefined, /* actually omitted */
  authType: null,
  eventId: string, /* event ID */
  eventType: "google.pubsub.topic.publish",
  params: {}, /* only relevant for RTDB */
  resource: "projects/<projectId>/topics/<topicName>",
  timestamp: string, /* time of the event as a RFC 3339 string */
}
```

You shouldn't need to explicitly import the `EventContext` type as it will be inferred automatically.

```js
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 5 minutes")
    .onRun((context) => {
        console.log(context.eventId)
    });
```

But if for some reason you did want to explicitly import it, you would use:

```js
import { EventContext } from "firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions";

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 5 minutes")
    .onRun((context: EventContext) => {
        console.log(context.eventId)
    });
```